# Automatic creation of database view from Django

Tags: django

Maybe this question also is similar to something like "automatic execution of raw SQL code just before creating exact one special model in models.py with managed=False".

For example, I have 3 models in models.py (default User, UserTypes and relation between them):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserTypes(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_types'


class UsersHaveTypes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(UserTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_have_types'
        unique_together = (("user", "type"), )
```

I have few types of users one of which is clients. Now I want to create endpoints "/clients", which will work as a usual model (CRUD).

Right now, I just add this in models.py:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    # all another fields from User model, which duplicated in the database view

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'clients'
```

and then I make this by hand in my database backend:

1. Create database view
2. Create a function to make Insert, Update
   and Delete
3. Create a trigger to trigger this functions.

It's a bunch of code and there is nothing special, all worked fine.

This all is to make working CRUD on "/clients" endpoint, so, for example, on "Creation", it will create User and automatically add a correct row to users_have_types table, which marks this user as "client".

Is there some more elegant and automatical way to make this? I move my Django project, and I need to create view, function, and trigger in the database backend again, which takes a lot of time (all by hand for every "type of users") and is an ugly decision.

I'm surprised, that nobody asked this question before, cause it's a good style of code database to make some views, and hide real table behind them. I know that Django can't create database view by self, but there must be a way to describe custom SQL code, which is used to create a table in the database. Maybe something with managers, I don't know (I'm a newbie in Django). Of course, it will be specific only for one database backend, but it's fine.

Comment: If you're using django-rest-framework, you can use `viewset`

Comment: @seuling, yes, I'm using django-rest-framework. Will look for it right now, thank you.

Comment: ok, please check docs [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/). it's well explained.

Comment: @seuling, looks like ViewSet work with a usual model (through serializer), which is determined in models.py, and don't automatically create the view in a database backend. Of course, I can set queryset to show "clients", but will it create a row in UsersHaveTypes that new User is "client"? As I can understand, no. Looks like it will just create User and don't make any update in other tables. Maybe it's possible to make in Django, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @VladimirOprya It looks like Django has no plans of adding support for creating Database Views through the ORM: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3361

Comment: Do check these packages on pypi to see if any are useful for your particular use-case.
1)https://pypi.org/project/django-database-view/#description

2)https://pypi.org/project/django-database-views/#description